# LinkedIn Oauth error: 'The partner did did not properly implement the authentication protocol' on browser back after signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, linkedin-api

We integrated a Rails app with linkedin authentication, using devise and the linkedin gem.
It works fine and able to register/sign in with linkedin, however an odd thing happens when you press 'back' on the browser after signing in/up:

It goes back to linkedin with the same request URL and the error shown is:

The partner did did not properly implement the authentication protocol.  in RED

This looks quite bad and we'd like to have a better way of handling this, but no idea where to start; any idea what could trigger this and is there any way we can prevent it?

Comment: hi did you get any solution to this problem ?

Comment: What protocol does your site use?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build your service for every new request.You might have same access code for diff-2 request.

Try to generate it for every http auth request.

```
service = new ServiceBuilder()
     .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
     .apiKey(API_KEY)
     .apiSecret(API_SECRET).debug()
     .build();
```